# Sorting csv according to particular column

Tags: javascript, sorting, csv

Hi I am exporting data to csv file using javascript. I need to sort the data according to specific column index.

Code:

```
      $.each(exportArray, function (index, value) {
csvData.push(x[index] + "," + y[index] + "," + d[index] + "," + z[index]  + ","+ a[index] + "," + e[index] + "," + b[index] + "," + c[index]);
        });
csvData.sort();

         csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(output);

      $(this)
.attr({
    'download': filename,
    'href': csvData,
    'target': '_blank'
});
```

E.g.: `csvData.sort()` is sorting data acoording to first column as default. I want to have it sorted according to the third column i.e.. by `d[index]`.
I tried this `csvData.sort(sort_by(d[index]));` and it is not working.

I have one more issue . Since I am exporting the data to csv. Now in `d[index]` from the server if I have three values like `d[index]="cat,dog,bat"` . It is getting displayed in 3 adjacent columns. I want it in the same column. Can I change the delimiter to something else from comma.

Code:

```
       csvData.push(x[index] + "," + y[index] + "," + d[index] + "," + z[index]  + ","+ a[index] + "," + e[index] + "," + b[index] + "," + c[index]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort the data before you write it to the CSV. This is more easily done if the data is in an array of objects instead of spread out in one array per property. To achive this you can either just put the data in objects when it is created or read, or you can convert it with a snippet like this:

```
var count = x.length;
var objects = new Array(count);
for(i=0; i++; i<count) {
    objects[i] = {
        x: x[i],
        y: y[i],
        d: d[i],
        z: z[i],
        a: a[i],
        e: e[i],
        b: b[i],
        c: c[i],
    };
}
```

Then you can easily sort the data, for example by the `x` property, with this code:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.x < b.x) return -1;
  if (a.x > b.x) return 1;
  return 0;
}

objects.sort(compare);
```

Then you will get the arrays sorted, and can access individual properties with for instance `objects[i].x`.

Comment: Hi Guys , thanks for the inputs. @Davide- Can you just let me know what is a and b in the compare function. Is it the first and second column?    Basically in my structure  X[index] is the first column and it will have n number of values down. Similarly Y[index] is the second column and it will have values etc in the csv file. Now if I only type CSV.sort() the first column values are getting sorted and rest column  values are filled accordingly. If I need to sort it according to any other column for eg:Y[index] what shall I do??

Comment: So far in the code any of us has posted, there is nothing names `CSV`, so I can not possibly understand what you are talking about. The solution I provided sorts according to the column of your choice - if you don't want `x`, just change the code to something else in the `compare` function.

Comment: The `a` and `b` variables are two different rows that are sent as input to `compare` by `sort`. `compare` should return `1` if `a` should be considered to be larger than `b`, `-1` if the reverse is the case, and `0` if they are equal, as per [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a custom `compare` function

```
// The following function is used to sort on the basis of the third element
function compareByThird(a, b) {
    var aArr = a.split(',');
    var bArr = b.split(',');
    return aArr[2] - bArr[2];
}

csvData.sort(compareByThird);
```

It works if the third column is a numeric value.
If not (for example for strings) it necessary to use the following code:

```
// The following function is used to sort on the basis of the third element
function compareByThird(a, b) {
    var aArr = a.split(',');
    var bArr = b.split(',');
    if (aArr[2] < bArr[2]) {
        return -1;
    } else if (aArr[2] > bArr[2] {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```